# How to post from Hootsuite to Google+?

Tags: google-plus, hootsuite

I have a Hootsuite account and use it to post to Twitter, Google+ and Facebook. My Google+ account has my personal profile and a business page. When I connect Hootsuite to my Google+ account, it only connects to the business page, which is where it sends any of my posts from Hootsuite.

Is there a way to connect to my personal Google+ account from Hootsuite instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that this feature is only available for Google+ pages, and not Google+ profiles.

[Source](https://help.hootsuite.com/entries/22345356-Why-can-t-I-add-my-Google-profile-).